# How to draw text of known width and height inside onDraw(Canvas canvas) method

Tags: android-custom-view

Here I am trying to make a Custom View containing text, I want to measure the text width and height so that I can also draw a background which fits the text of specific Measurment

Answer (score 0):

I'm just taking a guess here, use wrap_content in layout_width and layout_height parameters in XML

Comment: i am not using EditText or TextView i am just drawing Text using paint inside onDraw so how can i wrap the content?